# Android: selector for highlighting menu items?

Tags: android, user-interface, menu, selector

while I'm able to set "highlight color" for `ListView` items using `android:listSelector` 
attribute and appropriate selector, I'm unable to do the same, or something similar, 
for `Menu` items - they just keep using default system color scheme. I've read [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) article and found nothing there. Any clues?

Btw: I'm referring to `Menu` accessible via 'Menu' button.

Comment: The menu gotten by hitting `menu` is not a "context menu".  That said, I'm not sure it is possible to style that menu without just creating your own menu implementation.  I think they wanted the menu styling to be consistent across apps.

Comment: You're right, Mayra. I've corrected the post.